# How to enforce multiple unique sets (column-combinations) to be mutually-exclusive in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Consider a table containing null-able columns abc, def and xyz. How do I enforce:

1. Set 1 ('abc') to be UNIQUE if 'abc' is not null, and
2. Set 2 ('def, xyz') to be UNIQUE if both 'def' and 'xyz' are not null, and
3. Only one of the above sets is valid (contain non-nulls).

Here is the code I have tried:

```
--# sqlite3 --version
--  3.13.0 ....

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS try;
CREATE TABLE try(
    -- 'abc' should be null,                  when 'def' and 'xyz' are not null.
    -- 'abc' should be not be null,           when 'def' and 'xyz' are null.
    -- 'def' and 'xyz' should be null,        when 'abc' is not null.
    -- 'def' and 'xyz' should be not be null, when 'abc' is null.

    abc  TEXT,
    def  TEXT,
    xyz  TEXT,
    CONSTRAINT combo_1 UNIQUE(abc),
    CONSTRAINT combo_2 UNIQUE(def, xyz)
);

INSERT into try(abc)            VALUES("a1");              -- should succeed
INSERT into try(def, xyz)       VALUES("d2", "x2");        -- should succeed
--
INSERT into try(abc)            VALUES(null);              -- should not be allowed
INSERT into try(abc, def)       VALUES("a4", "d4");        -- should not be allowed
INSERT into try(abc, xyz)       VALUES("a5", "x5");        -- should not be allowed
INSERT into try(abc, def, xyz)  VALUES("a6", "d6", "x6");  -- should not be allowed
--
INSERT into try(def)            VALUES(null);              -- should not be allowed
INSERT into try(def)            VALUES("d8");              -- should not be allowed
--
INSERT into try(xyz)            VALUES(null);              -- should not be allowed
INSERT into try(xyz)            VALUES("x10");             -- should not be allowed
--
INSERT into try(def, xyz)       VALUES(null, null);        -- should not be allowed
INSERT into try(def, xyz)       VALUES("d12", null);       -- should not be allowed
INSERT into try(def, xyz)       VALUES(null, "x13");       -- should not be allowed

INSERT into try(abc, def, xyz)  VALUES(null, null, null);  -- should not be allowed

.headers ON
select rowid,* from try;

.echo on
--
-- Only these 2 rows should be present:
-- 1|a1||
-- 2||d2|x2
--
```

But, all the 14 inserts are succeeding, when I wanted only the first 2 to succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words: the NULL-ity of the `abc` and `def` columns should be different, while that of the `def` and `xyz` columns should be the same.

This can be done with two additional table constraints:

```
CHECK((abc IS NULL) <> (def IS NULL)),
CHECK((def IS NULL) =  (xyz IS NULL))
```

Comment: Thanks CL. I wanted to check if you could help me with another question I posted related to this (an extension of this): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45979764/