# How to enforce only a single set of fields to be non-NULL exclusively amongst multiple (more than 2) sets?

Tags: sql, sqlite

**Consider a setup such as this:**

- A table 'multi' to have these TEXT fields:  abc, def, ijk, lmn, uvw, xyz
- A set s1 to be a group of these fields:  abc, def
- A set s2 to be a group of these fields:  ijk, lmn
- A set s3 to be a group of these fields:  uvw, xyz

**How do I enforce data inserted into 'multi' is such that:**

- Only one of the sets can be valid in a row.
- A set is considered valid, if all fields in that set are non-NULL and non-empty.
- A set is considered invalid, if any field in that set is NULL or empty.
- A valid set has to unique across all rows.

This is related to [**an earlier similar question from me**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45957846/) (already answered), but wanted to see if a solution more optimal (eg: fewer constraints) than the working code below is possible:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS multi;
CREATE TABLE multi(
    --set1
    abc TEXT,
    def TEXT,

    --set2
    ijk TEXT,
    lmn TEXT,

    --set3
    uvw TEXT,
    xyz TEXT,

    -- If some member in a set is NULL, all have to be NULL.
    CONSTRAINT set1_null CHECK((abc is NULL) = (def is NULL)),
    CONSTRAINT set2_null CHECK((ijk is NULL) = (lmn is NULL)),
    CONSTRAINT set3_null CHECK((uvw is NULL) = (xyz is NULL)),

    -- If some member in a set in non-NULL, all have to be non-NULL
    CONSTRAINT set1_ntnl CHECK((abc is NOT NULL) = (def is NOT NULL)),
    CONSTRAINT set2_ntnl CHECK((ijk is NOT NULL) = (lmn is NOT NULL)),
    CONSTRAINT set3_ntnl CHECK((uvw is NOT NULL) = (xyz is NOT NULL)),

    -- A set cannot have members of empty strings.
    CONSTRAINT set1_ntmt CHECK((abc is NOT "") AND (def is NOT "")),
    CONSTRAINT set2_ntmt CHECK((ijk is NOT "") AND (lmn is NOT "")),
    CONSTRAINT set3_ntmt CHECK((uvw is NOT "") AND (xyz is NOT "")),

    -- If all members in a set are non-NULL, all others sets should only have NULL members.
    CONSTRAINT set1_excl CHECK((COALESCE(abc, def) is NOT NULL) = ((COALESCE(ijk, lmn) is NULL) AND COALESCE(uvw, xyz) is NULL))
    CONSTRAINT set1_excl CHECK((COALESCE(ijk, lmn) is NOT NULL) = ((COALESCE(uvw, xyz) is NULL) AND COALESCE(abc, def) is NULL))
    CONSTRAINT set1_excl CHECK((COALESCE(uvw, xyz) is NOT NULL) = ((COALESCE(abc, def) is NULL) AND COALESCE(ijk, lmn) is NULL))

    -- A set can have only unique combination of its non-NULL members.
    CONSTRAINT set1_uniq UNIQUE(abc, def),
    CONSTRAINT set2_uniq UNIQUE(lmn, ijk),
    CONSTRAINT set3_uniq UNIQUE(uvw, xyz)
);

.echo on
INSERT INTO multi(abc, def)  VALUES("a1", "d1");    -- should pass: unique set1
INSERT INTO multi(abc, def)  VALUES("a1", "d1");    -- should FAIL: duplicate set1

INSERT INTO multi(ijk, lmn)  VALUES("i3", "l3");    -- should pass: unique set2
INSERT INTO multi(ijk, lmn)  VALUES("i3", "l3");    -- should FAIL: duplicate set2

INSERT INTO multi(uvw, xyz)  VALUES("u5", "x5");    -- should pass: unique set3
INSERT INTO multi(uvw, xyz)  VALUES("u5", "x5");    -- should FAIL: duplicate set3

INSERT INTO multi(abc, def)  VALUES(NULL, NULL);    -- should FAIL: null set1
INSERT INTO multi(ijk, lmn)  VALUES(NULL, NULL);    -- should FAIL: null set2
INSERT INTO multi(uvw, xyz)  VALUES(NULL, NULL);    -- should FAIL: null set3

INSERT INTO multi(abc, def)  VALUES("", "");        -- should FAIL: empty set1
INSERT INTO multi(ijk, lmn)  VALUES("", "");        -- should FAIL: empty set2
INSERT INTO multi(uvw, xyz)  VALUES("", "");        -- should FAIL: empty set3

INSERT INTO multi(abc)       VALUES(NULL);          -- should FAIL: incomplete set1
INSERT INTO multi(abc)       VALUES("");            -- should FAIL: incomplete set1
INSERT INTO multi(abc)       VALUES("a15");         -- should FAIL: incomplete set1
INSERT INTO multi(abc, ijk)  VALUES("a16", "i16");  -- should FAIL: incomplete set1

INSERT into multi(abc, def, ijk, lmn, uvw, xyz)  VALUES("", "", "", "", "", "");  -- should FAIL:
INSERT into multi(abc, def, ijk, lmn, uvw, xyz)  VALUES(null, null, null, null, null, null);  -- should FAIL:
INSERT into multi(abc, def, ijk, lmn, uvw, xyz)  VALUES("a19", "b19", "", "", null, null); -- should FAIL:
-- etc

-- ------------------------------------
-- Only these 3 rows should be present:
-- ##|abc|def|ijk|lmn|uvw|xyz
-- 1 |a1 |d1 |   |   |   |
-- 2 |   |   |i3 |l3 |   |
-- 3 |   |   |   |   |u5 |x5
-- ------------------------------------
.headers ON
select rowid AS ROW, * from multi;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the `setX_ntnl` constraints; IS NULL and IS NOT NULL always return opposite results.

The `setX_excl` constraints do not need to use COALESCE because the earlier `setX_null` constraints already enforce that all columns in a set have the same kind of value; you could simply compare one column in each set.
And there is an easier method to check that exactly one of the three sets is valid: the number of valid sets must be one:

```
CONSTRAINT set123_excl CHECK((abc IS NOT NULL) +
                             (ijk IS NOT NULL) +
                             (uvw IS NOT NULL) = 1)
```

(In SQLite, boolean expressions return `0` or `1`.)

Comment: Indeed a cool idea, but how does this come to be the accepted solution? Just curious, because it only reduces the count of constraints by two; it still relies on the presence of numerous other constraints to function. I thought the OP was specifically looking to reduce the number of constraints considerably.. (i.e., to one or two)

Comment: @CaiusJard I guess he was actually looking for simplicity.

Comment: This worked for all test cases I had listed (including the additional one mentioned by Cais Jard). So, I accepted it as answer - but did not realize StackOverflow will undo my previous accept.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use SQLite but I read that using || to concatenate strings will produce a null result if one string is null. This is useful because we can ensure that both strings are not null by concatting them. `a || b` must mean that both are non null otherwise null results. I also think that SQLite treats empty string and null as different, meaning we have to check that `a || b` isn't the same as a or b..

A basic set checking then could be `COALESCE(a || b, '') NOT IN (a, b, '')`:

- If a or b (or both) is null, null results, the COALESCE converts it to empty string, empty string is one of the set the result must be NOT IN
- If a and b are both empty string, an empty string results from the coalesce and again it is a member of the "not allowed" set
- If a is a value and b is empty, the result is a (and that is a member of "not allowed". A similar logic follows for b having a value and a being empty

The logic proves only one set. If a row must have only one of 3 sets specified, then it must be "prove first set alone" OR "prove second set alone" OR "prove third set alone"

To prove a set is alone on the row, after proving it valid with the tests above, we must test the other sets that their values are all only empty strings. The easiest way to do this is to concatenate them all and ensure the result is just an empty string. If any value is longer than 0, the result is not an empty string. If any value is null, the result is not an empty string

Here's the complete (and only) constraint needed:

```
CONSTRAINT a CHECK
(

  (COALESCE(abc || def, '') NOT IN (abc, def, '') AND ijk||lmn||uvw||xyz='')
  OR
  (COALESCE(ijk || lmn, '') NOT IN (ijk, lmn, '') AND abc||def||uvw||xyz='')
  OR
  (COALESCE(uvw || xyz, '') NOT IN (uvw, xyz, '') AND abc||def||ijk||lmn='')

)
```

Making a primary key of abc,def,ijk,lmn,uvw,xyz should be the only other thing that is needed to implement the uniqueness feature too, unless a set of (abc='a',def='b') is the same as (abc='b',def='a')

Be careful that this is not "brevity at the expense of clarity"

Comment: >abc,def,ghi,jkl,uvw,xyz
> i3, j3, '', '',nul,nul
Your complete constraint worked fine for me in sqlite3.
However, the above test case passed, though for my application it should have failed. If you know of a way to add this to the complete constraint or as additional constraint, please do let me know. In anycase, thanks a lot for your help..

Comment: What is the failure though? I couldn't work out whether the blank spaces in your example data were empty strings or nulls..

Comment: Those are empty strings (I use double quotes instead of single quotes for strings, out of habit - and might have caused the confusion). Your suggestion works fine, except for the test case you pointed out.

Comment: So you want to ensure that a populated set is only found on a row where the other sets are empty strings?

Comment: Thanks Caius Jard. I applied solution (after your edit), but it still fails (in sqlite3) for the new case you had mentioned. This is definitely more concise for me though, and I have not yet done any performance comparison.